# How can i make one function repeat by pressing button several times in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

numL = 0
numD = 0

root.geometry("200x100")

def like():
    root_label1.config(text=numL+1)

def dlike():
    root_label2.config(text=numD+1)

root_button1 = Button(root, text="Like", command=like)
root_button2 = Button(root, text="Dislike", command=dlike)

root_label1 = Label(root, text=numL)
root_label2 = Label(root, text=numD)

root_button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root_button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root_label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
root_label2.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This code is working without errors but when I press like or dislike button the labels change from 0 to 1 only one time then nothing happens however what I want is when ever I press any button the numbers keep on adding themselves with one.

Comment: You did not update `numL` and `numD` inside the two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def like():
    global numL
    numL+=1
    root_label1.config(text=numL)
    

def dlike():
    global numD
    numD+=1
    root_label2.config(text=numD)
```

You need to update the `numL` and `numD`. Your function fetches the value of `numL` and `numD` as 0 because you never update it.

Comment: It should be `numL`

Comment: I changed it to `numL` still doesn't work

Comment: Shows:  local variable 'numL' referenced before assignment

Comment: So you need to use global keyword or pass it as a argument

Comment: @PCM Make all the comments onto a single one, instead of spamming.

Comment: Better to move `num+=1` above `config` so you can just `config(text=numL)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lists to make it easier. Also, `len()` and more functions can be used -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

numL = []
numD = []

root.geometry("200x100")

def like():
       numL.append(0)
       root_label1.config(text=len(numL))

def dlike():
    numD.append(0)
    root_label2.config(text=len(numD))

root_button1 = Button(root, text="Like", command=like)
root_button2 = Button(root, text="Dislike", command=dlike)

root_label1 = Label(root, text=len(numL))
root_label2 = Label(root, text=len(numD))

root_button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root_button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root_label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
root_label2.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

I used `len(lists)` for the text. This worked for me. And it should work for you

Comment: Why would you make `numL` and `numD` lists? Lists take up more memory than integers so there is no point. Also appending to a list takes more time than adding 1 to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

global numL
numL = 0
numD = 0

root.geometry("200x100")

def like():
    numL = int(str(root_label1['text']))
    numL = numL+1
    root_label1.config(text=numL)

def dlike():
    numD = int(str(root_label2['text']))
    numD = numD + 1
    root_label2.config(text=numD)

root_button1 = Button(root, text="Like", command= like)
root_button2 = Button(root, text="Dislike", command=dlike)

root_label1 = Label(root, text=numL)
root_label2 = Label(root, text=numD)

root_button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root_button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root_label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
root_label2.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

You should save new values in variables

Comment: I think you missed `global`.

Comment: I just rewrite the functions. Global variables are in the main code.

Comment: @ShamimSanisales this will raise `UnboundLocalError` [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Pass numL and numD as aa argument to your functions. I believe this can work.

Comment: @ShamimSanisales That isn't going to work because you are passing it by value not by reference.

Comment: you are right, check it now. It's work for me. so I should work for you too :)

Comment: This solution is much slower than @ Sujay's solution. In your case you get a string object and then pass it through `str` then `int`, then you store it, add 1 to it, and then use it.

Comment: I use this one because globalization is not a really safe solution. and also it's another way for solving this question.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be this :-
from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
numLvar = 0
numL = StringVar()
numL.set(numLvar)
numDvar = 0
numD = StringVar()
numD.set(numDvar)

root.geometry("200x100")

def like():
    global numLvar
    # root_label1.config(text=numL+1)
    numLvar += 1
    numL.set(numLvar)
    root_label1.update()


def dlike():
    global numDvar
    # root_label1.config(text=numL+1)
    numDvar += 1
    numD.set(numDvar)
    root_label2.update()

root_button1 = Button(root, text="Like", command=like)
root_button2 = Button(root, text="Dislike", command=dlike)

root_label1 = Label(root, textvariable=numL)
root_label2 = Label(root, textvariable=numD)

root_button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root_button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root_label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
root_label2.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Code explanation :
whenever you want to change the text in a label... text = text will not work.... you need textvariable = varname for this purpose and it must be a supported vaiable type in tkinter... here i have used StringVar as its the most convinient one..... also after changing its value in function... you need to set the textvariable again using the .set() method.... and also use .update() for the label to update it to the last set value...

hope it helps... it is working i have checked....

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try to use lambda function if u know what I mean. That does mean: `command = lambda: like`. I didnt try it but i guess it should work:)

Comment: did you mean: `command=lambda: like()` also not necessary if no arguments are passed, so this is probably not the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

numL = 0
numD = 0

root.geometry("200x100")

def like():
    global numL
    root_label1.config(text=numL+1)
    numL = numL + 1

def dlike():
    global numD
    root_label2.config(text=numD+1)
    numD = numD + 1

root_button1 = Button(root, text="Like", command=like)
root_button2 = Button(root, text="Dislike", command=dlike)

root_label1 = Label(root, text=numL)
root_label2 = Label(root, text=numD)

root_button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root_button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root_label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
root_label2.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Its working !

Comment: While this works, it is better to avoid globalizing variables, the list method by PCM seems fine. Also it is better to `numD = numD + 1` above `config` and use `+=` as it is more pythonic, and check `+1` inside `config()` too

Comment: @CoolCloud The list variables used by PCM are also global variables, so your comment *"avoid globalizing variables"* applies to it as well.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah yea, I did not think of that. Then better to pass parameters